# How to create an example class in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++

1. How we can create a class of anything like car.
2. Now think of elements that should be the part of that class. At least think of 8 elements.
3. At least instantiate 5 objects of that class.

Comment: Your homework, your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write your homework due dates down
2. Don't leave your homework til last minute
3. Try before asking in SO